# Writing an ethernet driver for TiM551

Tags: ros, lidar, driver, ethernet, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this driver for the TiM551

```
http://wiki.ros.org/sick_tim3xx
```

It worked really well, but I want to take advantage of the TiM551's IP67 rating. This means I can't use the usb on the side. I'm new to writing drivers for devices and not particularly knowledgeable on networking. Is there a guide out there for me to follow? I've been studying up on the LMS1xx driver, but I don't know if its enough to help me write it.

I would imagine the first step is to use wireshark to understand how the message is formatted.

Learning how to write drivers would be really helpful, I wouldn't want to be limited from just whats currently available.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141491/writing-an-ethernet-driver-for-tim551/) by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2014-03-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The author of the driver informed me TCP is already supported with the current driver. It was just updated on the documentation and works wonderfully!

---

Originally posted by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) with karma: 447 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1